# can't reach gui element using Timepicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I followed the guidelines on google: [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker)

I created a new class `TimePickerFragment`, but in my `onTimeSet` method I can't reach the gui element to update the picked time.

any ideas?

Comment: instead of creating a new class, you could implement it as a nested class to get rid of the scope problems...

Comment: never did that, but I'll give it a try